# querygrain() problem with "length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent"

Tags: r, graph, bayesian, bayesian-networks

Looking at the answers for others that had also encountered the following error

> Error in array(values, dimnames = dn) :
> length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

I did not find any posts that applied to me as my data is not in a data frame but instead in a graph I think. Anyone has ideas on why this may be occurring?

My code is the following

```
library(Rtools)
library(RBGL)
library(graph)
library(pcalg)
library(dplyr)
library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)
library(ellipsis)
library(varhandle)
library(gRain)

P1 = 0.0940594059405941
P2 = 0.0033003300330033
P3 = 0.0214521452145215
P4 = 0.0602310231023102
P5 = 0.00907590759075908
P6 = 0.033003300330033
P7 = 0.0132013201320132
P8 = 0.765676567656766
P9 = 0.0808580858085809
P10 = 0.0115511551155116
P11 = 0.0585808580858086
P12 = 0.849009900990099
P13 = 0.0899339933993399
P14 = 0.0313531353135314
P15 = 0.00247524752475248
P16 = 0.876237623762376
P17 = 0.114686468646865
P18 = 0.0643564356435644
P19 = 0.0066006600660066
P20 = 0.814356435643564
P21 = 0.179042904290429
P22 = 0.820957095709571

ABCA9 = cptable(~ABCA9|BTNL9:IGSF10, values=c(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8),levels=tf)
IGSF10 = cptable(~IGSF10|class, values=c(P9,P10,P11,P12),levels=tf)
class = cptable(~class|CD300LG, values=c(P13,P14,P15,P16),levels=tf)
CD300LG = cptable(~CD300LG|BTNL9, values=c(P17,P18,P19,P20),levels=tf)
BTNL9 = cptable(~BTNL9, values=c(P21,P22),levels=tf)
plist2 = compileCPT(list(ABCA9,IGSF10,class,CD300LG,BTNL9))

net1=grain(plist2)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,0))
plot(net1$dag)
```

The problem occurs when I try and run the following queries to find the probabilities:

```
querygrain(net1, nodes=c('ABCA9','IGSF10','BTNL9','CD300LG'),type=joint)
querygrain(net1, nodes=c('class', 'BTNL9','CD300LG'),type=conditional)
```

Other wise if I do a query like this I don't get any errors:

```
querygrain(net1, nodes=c('class', 'CD300LG'),type=conditional)
```

I don't think this error only happens because I haven't previously specified those specific probabilities in my Bayesian graph, As in my practical they were able to perform a query like what I have done without getting an error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error -- that is, all queries execute  -- BUT to run your example I had to add `tf = c("t", "f")` and quotes around `conditional` and `joint` e.g. `type="conditional"`. I also only loaded `gRain` and `Rgraphviz` as they are the only required packages for your example.

Comment: Does the problem persist in a fresh R session, without loading any previous workspace? Probably worth adding the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question in case there is a version issue.

Comment: @user20650 Interesting, the error didn't repeat again. Thanks I guess restarting the R session helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just had to restart the R session and change tf = c("t", "f") which is what I did as well to make it work. Before I had tf = c(1,0).

Comment: Indeed using `tf = c(1,0)` is the source of the error. The levels need to be character although this doesn't seem to be mentioned in the help page. So if you really want `0/1` you could use `tf = c("1","0")`